# Kafka consumer configuration difference

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka consumer (written in python). It listens to topics with regex(^.*_collection_updates$).

I have seen that the connection between consumer and brokers stops and starts automatically. I don't know the reason. Can someone tell me diff between below stack overlflow listed configuration ?

The answer in this issue is the configuration i wanted to know.

- [Sometimes a new consumer group does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319885/sometimes-a-new-consumer-group-does-not-work)

Comment: How many partitions you have ? How many consumer groups? How many consumers ? Which version of Kafka?

Comment: partition - 1 , consumer_groups - 4 , consumers - 4 , kafka_version - confluent-kafka==0.11.6

Comment: Did you try 'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest' ? Default value of this parameter is latest https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs.

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Comment: Just want to know , difference between first and second below.

1.The problem seems to have been in the Consumer() arguments. This doesn't work properly:

self.kafka_consumer = confluent_kafka.Consumer({
    'group.id': 'mygroup',
    'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka:9092',
    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
})
2.But this does:

self.kafka_consumer = confluent_kafka.Consumer({
    'group.id': 'mygroup',
    'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka:9092',
    'default.topic.config': {
        'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
    },
})

Comment: That is too vague. What kind of error are you getting in 1st case? Have you checked kafka document? Is default.topic.config a parameter that consumer accepts?

Comment: I am marking this question vague.